# unable to install rhdfs in centos

Tags: r, hadoop, hdfs, rstudio, rstudio-server

```
$ sudo R CMD INSTALL rhdfs
* installing to library ‘/usr/lib64/R/library’
* installing *source* package ‘rhdfs’ ...
** R
** inst
** preparing package for lazy loading
** help
*** installing help indices
  converting help for package ‘rhdfs’
    finding HTML links ... done
    hdfs-file-access                        html  
    hdfs-file-manip                         html  
    hdfs.defaults                           html  
    hdfs.file-level                         html  
    initialization                          html  
    rhdfs                                   html  
    text.files                              html  
** building package indices
** testing if installed package can be loaded
Error : .onLoad failed in loadNamespace() for 'rhdfs', details:
  call: fun(libname, pkgname)
  error: Environment variable HADOOP_CMD must be set before loading package rhdfs
Error: loading failed
Execution halted
ERROR: loading failed
* removing ‘/usr/lib64/R/library/rhdfs’
```

I have tried doing many round of iterations, still no go. Iam unable to install rhdfs and rmr2. I have already set HADOOP_CMD, JAVA_HOME, PATH AND installed rjava in R evironment in cludera. Iam unable to load rhdfs at all. Please help with this, or should I uninstall everything from R - R, Studio and reinstall again. Please help..

When I try installing rhdfs in R it gives me this error:

```
> install.packages("rhdfs")
Installing package into ‘/home/supstat/R/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu-library/2.13’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
Warning in install.packages :
  package ‘rhdfs’ is not available (for R version 3.1.0)
```

Comment: Open R and try `Sys.getenv("HADOOP_CMD")` and check if the value is correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I faced several issues while trying to install RHadoop, and all of them had to do with rjava. Export the `HADOOP_CMD` and `HADOOP_STREAMING` variables. After that, you need to tell R library path to point to where your Java installation is:

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle/jre/lib/amd64/server
```

Then, you need to run the following command:

```
R CMD javareconf -e
```

After that you should be able to install rhdfs and rmr2. If I remember correctly you need to install rmr2 before installing rhdfs, or maybe it was the other way around.

**EDIT:** try to configure it and install from inside R:

```
Sys.setenv(HADOOP_CMD="the same value you used outside R")
Sys.setenv(HADOOP_STREAMING="same as above")
install.packages("rhdfs_1.0.8.tar.gz", repos=NULL, type="source")
```

Comment: How are you installing it? Did you download it from github?

Comment: yes I installed it from github (https://github.com/RevolutionAnalytics/RHadoop/wiki/user%3Erhdfs%3EHome)

Comment: Open R with sudo ant try `Sys.getenv("HADOOP_CMD")`, is the value correct? Or is it empty?

Comment: yes it shows empty, when i say echo HADOOP_CMD it just show as HADOOP_CMD, but when i do > Sys.getenv("HADOOP_CMD")
[1] "/usr/bin/hadoop"

Comment: Ok I didn't get that. If it displays correctly "/usr/bin/hadoop" it is not empty. You did it with `sudo R`, right? As for the `echo HADOOP_CMD`, it shows HADOOP_CMD because you need to add a $ when dealing with variables: `echo $HADOOP_CMD`.

Comment: Still if its working its not helping with installing rhdfs and rmr2 package, will it help if i uninstall r and install it again, i have tried updating the r with new version.. After that i keep getting u have installed version which is supported with rhdfs..

Comment: See my edit and try that out. Use the same values for both variables you used when exporting them outside R. As for the `install.packages` command, use the name of the package you downloaded.

Comment: still same results ---- '> install.packages("rhdfs_1.0.8.tar.gz", repos=NULL, type="source")
Installing package into ‘/home/supstat/R/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu-library/2.13’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
Warning: invalid package ‘rhdfs_1.0.8.tar.gz’
Error: ERROR: no packages specified
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘rhdfs_1.0.8.tar.gz’ had non-zero exit status'

Comment: I tried giving the path of the folder where the rhdfs tar file is in the same command still no go.. install.packages("<path>/rhdfs_1.0.8.tar.gz", repos=NULL, type="source")

Answer (score 0):

1. In .bashrc file add the following line at the end
   export LD_LIBRARY_PATH="/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/lib/amd64/server"
2. source the bashrc file or simply close the terminal and open a new one
3. $ R CMD javareconf -e
4. $ R
5. Within R run the following commands:

   > Sys.setenv(HADOOP_CMD="/home//hadoop-2.5.0-cdh5.3.2/bin/hadoop")
   >   Sys.setenv(HADOOP_STREAMING="/home//hadoop-2.5.0-cdh5.3.2/bin/hadoop")
   >   install.packages("/home//Downloads/rhbase_1.2.1.tar.gz", repos=NULL, type="source")

This is assuming rhbase_1.2.1.tar.gz is under Downloads directory inside home directory